# How to resolve notary double spend error in the running network? - Unable to notarise the transactions

Tags: corda

There is a dev-network in my project which is including Accounts-sdk, Token-sdk. The project is about transfer of custom tokens between accounts of same node as well as different node. The network is suddenly not notarising the transition which was working for a long time. Now I am not able to transfer the tokens and I am able to transfer the token if I issue the fresh token and transfer. After two or three transactions of transfer the network is again not notarising the transaction.

Throwing
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.core.flows.NotaryException: Unable to notarise transaction AD57C34EA40953561B90C5EB832336E4E42CD2C876CA5030C986B9EB50909AE7 : One or more input states or referenced states have already been used as input states in other transactions. Conflicting state count: 1, consumption details: today at 1:05:43 PM14BBC38DF7BDA1FD6CA8E97DB16967FBFC9B18AB95DCD7B1990892C206759FA3(1) -> StateConsumptionDetails(hashOfTransactionId=6190DA0ABAD95B767AB42351368A1D51FCCE164DD08D256F98E065F54B6EE789, type=INPUT_STATE). today at 1:05:43 PMTo find out if any of the conflicting transactions have been generated by this node you can use the hashLookup Corda shell command.] with root cause today at 1:05:43 PM net.corda.core.flows.NotaryException: Unable to notarise transaction AD57C34EA40953561B90C5EB832336E4E42CD2C876CA5030C986B9EB50909AE7 : One or more input states or referenced states have already been used as input states in other transactions. Conflicting state count: 1, consumption details: today at 1:05:43 PM14BBC38DF7BDA1FD6CA8E97DB16967FBFC9B18AB95DCD7B1990892C206759FA3(1) -> StateConsumptionDetails(hashOfTransactionId=6190DA0ABAD95B767AB42351368A1D51FCCE164DD08D256F98E065F54B6EE789, type=INPUT_STATE). today at 1:05:43 PMTo find out if any of the conflicting transactions have been generated by this node you can use the hashLookup Corda shell command.`

I am not able to understand why the transfer of token is not been notarised.

1. Why the network went un-notarising the transfer tokens transaction?
2. how can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the transaction used to transfer the token is using an input reference that has already been consumed. You can see the transaction id and the output index that is creating the problem in the error description, which could be of some help to debug the issue.

Comment: Please share some code of the flows involved for further assistance.

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh The code was working fine for a long time. Instantly the error has come. After no possiblity to make transfer. So how can I resolve it using the hashOfTransactionId?  I have no clue to resolve it. Will you please detailly explain me the ways to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @gokulnath, any update or solution got on this?